# Extra regs being created during synthesis

Tags: verilog, synthesis

Say I have 2 multi-bit regs in design. Both of them share a common condition (`cond_x`) as their enable but 1 of them has an extra condition (`cond_y`) apart from `reset` signal for when its meant to be reset.

Example (ignoring reset part of code for simplicity) -

1. Same always block

   ```
   always @(posedge clock) begin
     if(cond_x) begin
       a <= a_next;
       b <= b_next;
     else if(cond_y) begin
       b <= 5'b0;
     end
   end
   ```
2. Different always blocks

   ```
   always @(posedge clock) begin
     if(cond_x) begin
       a <= a_next;
     end
   end

   always @(posedge clock) begin
     if(cond_x) begin
       b <= b_next;
     else if(cond_y) begin
       b <= 5'b0;
     end
   end
   ```

When I synthesize 2 i get more number of regs than are expected in the design. Using 1 it is accurate. The extra regs are only for lower two bits of `b` and are suffixed by `__rep1`. Not sure what that means or how it is being created.

Is there any possible reason for the same? I am using Synopsys DC

Comment: I'm not familiar with Synposys DC, but it might be logic duplication, in order to reduce the load on the critical path for timing improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design Compiler can replicate cells to improve timing, load etc. and the replicated cells get the suffix `_rep<n>`. The [datasheet](https://www.synopsys.com/content/dam/synopsys/implementation&signoff/datasheets/dc-ultra-ds.pdf) of DC Ultra has the following explanation:

> DC Ultra looks at a larger subsection of the critical path during
>   logic duplication and can **replicate** many gates to reduce load of high
>   fan-out nets, hence improving timing on critical paths through load
>   isolation.

However the two code snippets seem identical, DC can produce different results depending on the starting conditions. Most probably the second code was synthesized into a worse circuit for `b[1:0]` and the tool had to replicate these two flip-flops.

Comment: Thanks @ahmedus. What coding style out of the 2 would you prefer/recommend?

Comment: @kevin1494 The 1st code is shorter, but  2nd one is clearer. Hard to decide... :)